# Clone hard disk while PXE booting

Tags: networking, boot, pxe

I would like to boot a PC from the network (e.g., PXE), then let the PC clone its hard disk from an image located on a server, then boot from the hard disk.

Is it possible?

FAI (fully automatic install) seems not to support cloning an entire image.

Another solution I found would be to use dd and netcat for cloning over the network. However, I would have to somehow first boot a minimalistic system that has dd and netcat available, then clone, then re-boot from hard disk. Is this possible? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: I think it is possible! It should be easy if USB boot is acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean? Just booting the system from the USB stick? But how is that related to my question?

Answer (score 1):

FAI is good for netbooting an installer.  To netboot a disk image cloner, use [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org), which specializes in Windows imaging, or [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org), which supports OS-agnostic images.

Comment: Seems that FOG only supports Windows clients.

Comment: Added suggestion for Clonezilla.

Comment: Yes, I know about Clonezilla. You can use it, e.g., to boot from CD/USB and then clone a drive. But how could you use it to boot from network, clone a partition from server to your machine, and then boot from this partition?

Comment: @Konstantin, CloneZilla does support PXE http://clonezilla.org/livepxe.php . I have tested that before, for better performance use an NFS share for images store (instead of HTTP/FTP/SSH)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You need to use minimalistic initramfs/initrd, whose job is to `dd` local HDD from network. Once done, mount that partition and chmod to that image.